# Possible bug in getValidationMessages

Tags: breeze

I've created a custom entity level validation function, very similar to the one in the documentation (http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation). When I call getValidationErrors(), I get the following error:

*Cannot read property 'name' of undefined*

The error is coming from:

```
proto.getValidationErrors = function (property) {
    assertParam(property, "property").isOptional().isEntityProperty().or().isString().check();
    var result = __getOwnPropertyValues(this._validationErrors);
    if (property) {
        var propertyName = typeof (property) === 'string' ? property : property.name;
        result = result.filter(function (ve) {
            **return (ve.property.name === propertyName);**
        });
    }
    return result;
};
```

There is no 'property' field in the custom entity level validator context. I'm using Breeze 1.4.5. Is this a bug? It seems to me the code above should check for 've.property', before trying to access the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

This has been fixed as of Breeze 1.4.7, available now.

### Previous Post:

This is a bug that has already been fixed on GitHub and will be part of the next release (Breeze 1.4.7) out sometime next week. Or you can pull the breeze.xxx.js file from GitHub now if you need the fix earlier.